# Check if the position is the same from the list

Tags: c#

I added the IsClicked Method(bool) into the list. At the same time, I want to make sure the IsClicked Method(x,y) is not the same from the list.

```
  if (CheckInput()) {
    string name = textBoxName.Text;
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
    decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text);
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;


    Plant plant = new Plant(name, size, price, x, y);
    plantsList.Add(plant);
    totalCost =plantsList.Sum(item => item.Price);


   if(plantsList.Any(n => n.IsClicked(x, y) == 
                       plant.IsClicked(x, y)))
            {

                MessageBox.Show("You draw at the same position");
            }


                pictureBoxGarden.Refresh();
  }
```

Display a Message if they are the same.

Comment: Pease look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: public class Plant{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

  public bool IsClicked(int x, int y)
        {
            return (x - _x) * (x - _x) + (y - _y) * (y - _y) <= (_size * 
             _size);
        }
}

Comment: This is the class with the method.

Comment: And what is your problem? What do you **expect** and what do you get instead?

Comment: My problem is the message box will keep saying "You draw at the same position" every single time even though I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first check if there's such a `plant` in the `plantsList` and only then `Add`:

```
  ...

  // plant we are going to add
  Plant plant = new Plant(name, size, price, x, y);

  // Do we have such a plant in the list?
  if (plantsList.Any(item => item.IsClicked(x, y) == plant.IsClicked(x, y))) 
  {
      MessageBox.Show("You draw at the same position");
  } 
  else 
  {
      // if no, let's add it and compute the new lotal cost 
      plantsList.Add(plant);
      totalCost = plantsList.Sum(item => item.Price); 
  } 

  pictureBoxGarden.Refresh();
```